# Pip --user installs package to Default user directory on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, pip, windows-10

I have a problem on Windows 10 where both Python 2.6 and 2.7 are installed.

```
python -m pip install myPack --no-index --find-links=. --user
```

When running this command with user *AutoUser* it installs *myPack* to *Default* user directory C:\Users\Default\Python\Python27\site-packages or C:\Users\Default\Appdata\Roaming\Python\site-packages **instead** C:\Users\Autouser\Appdata\Roaming\Python\site-packages

- Installation is automatic soon after windows logon, but I can see in logs that "query user" returns a row with *AutoUser* (before calling pip).
- Other OS don't have this problem.
- Reproduction is unstable on Windows 10: maybe 1 time of 100.
- Truth that python 2.6 is also installed on these machines, but I'm not sure it is meaningful: 2.6 goes later than 2.7 in Path system variable. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47043711/the-module-has-been-successfully-installed-but-then-its-not-found-when-imported) they write it could be a problem, but pip doesn't confuse python versions, it confuses users' directories.

---

Path:

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts\;C:\Python26\;C:\Python26\Scripts;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;
```

Python version:

```
python --version
Python 2.7.13
```

Pip version:

```
python -m pip --version
Pip version: pip 9.0.1 from C:\Python27\lib\site-packages (python 2.7)
```

Comment: I think this answer will be useful.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34803087/5774004

Comment: What is the value of %APPDATA%?

Comment: From the commands you ran, it's clear that *Python 2.6* doesn't have anything to do here. But what about the real scenario? How is the install triggered? Is is from a service? What is the user that launches the command? You should print its environment before launching the command. **Always specify the full path** when there's a chance for confusion. So it's not reproducible? Are you sure that some previous module installation doesn't have anything to do?

Comment: @CristiFati, install is triggered automatically from our software: 1) it restores a target VM to the default snapshot, 2) waits for a handshake from a built-in "dropper" service; 3) sends command to this "dropper" to run powershell script containing "pip install". 4) Script is run as AutoUser (I logged it with 'query user'). I failed to reliably reproduce the issue. As for printing environment, what exactly would you recommend besides PATH? Other modules definitely have nothing to do here: they do not use python at all.

Answer (score 10):

You can try setting the install target with the `--target` option like so:

```
pip install --target=C:\Users\Autouser\Appdata\Roaming\Python\site-packages package_name
```

If that doesn't work, another option is to try using `--install-option` like this:

```
pip install --install-option="--prefix=$PREFIX_PATH" package_name
```

Finally, if all else fails, here's one more way to do it:

```
PYTHONUSERBASE=/path/to/install/to pip install --user
```

You can specify which python version to install the package for by using `python2.x -m pip install ...`

Hopefully one of these helps you! :)

Comment: None of those worked for me.  What did work was adding `<absolute-path>\site-packages\ ` (and `<same-absolute-path\Scripts\ `) to my Windows PATH env var.  :(  So ugly.  I never had this issue when developing with Python on Linux.  Maybe helpful to someone else: somewhere else on SO I found that `pip3 show <package-name>` gave me the path to the install location.

Answer (score 1):

Try running cmd as admin when installing

Comment: Using an admin cmd prompt caused `pip install <package>` to install the package into e.g. `c:\program files\python39\scripts`, whereas a non-admin cmd prompt installed it into e.g. `c:\users\<user>\appdata\roaming\python\python39\scripts'.

Answer (score 0):

**CMD Prompt non-administrator, installed for current user:**

Location: C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\Scripts

[image]

**CMD Prompt as ADMINISTRATOR, installed for all users**:

C:\Program Files\Python\Scripts

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Unfortunately I had to fix the problem in production quickly, so I gave up and installed it without the --user option to c:/python27/... directory.
I guess one of @DeltaMarine101 suggestions would help.

Comment: "I give up" is not a Solution. This would be fine if it were moved to a Comment, but it shouldn't be here as an Answer, especially the Accepted Answer.